# Truffle is not compiling neither is it rather gives error "Cannot find module"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/acer/blockchain-home/truffle-config.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at Object.require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Function.load (/home/soyaya/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/index.js:159:1)
at Function.detect (/home/soyaya/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/index.js:148:1)
at Object.run (/home/soyaya/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:194:1)
at Command.run (/home/soyaya/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:172:1)
```

Truffle v5.4.10 (core: 5.4.10)
Node v10.19.0

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is harder to read and understand, and ALL CAPS will not get you an answer any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here shouting at us when you're asking us for free help to solve a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured it out
in my truffle.config file i edited require('babel-register'); to require('@babel/register');

then i installed babel/register

i edited require('babel-polyfill'); to require('@babel/polyfill');
then i installed babel/polyfill
it worked my truffle passed and compiled

Answer (score 0):

fix this problem by running the following:
npm install -g babel-runtime

You can find the full thread about this truffle bug here:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5074